# how to access sub class properties of object.GetType() when only have the name of the sub class as a string

Tags: c#, inheritance, model-view-controller, reflection

I'm trying to assemble a generic method which is passed an object of a class type (ie: dbJob) and also the name of a sub class like 'LastUpdatedDate' and a process string, which can be '> 01-01-2015'.

The method looks like this

```
public bool checkProcess(object obj, string className, string processStr)
{
    PropertyInfo[] propertyInfo;
    bool returnValue = false;
    propertyInfo = obj.GetType().GetProperties();
    //propertyInfo className evaluate processStr
    return returnValue; 
}
```

I'm using Reflection to get the property information for my Class. Say I'm passing dbJob, how can I use the string say 'LastUpdatedDate' for the sub class to get me the properties to evaluate processStr?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply try to cast it `as` that type, if it successfully can be cast then get the properties from that instance type.

```
var subClass = obj as SubClass;
if ( subClass != null )
{
    var type = subClass.GetType();
    var props = type.GetProperties();
    ...
}
```

As a comment, if you have control over the classes you would be better off using interfaces for this sort of thing.

Define the interface:

```
public interface IYourInterface 
{
   string SomeMethod();
}
```

Implement the interface on your class:  (classes can implement as many interfaces as needed)

```
public class YourSub : IYourInterface
{
   ... other methods/props ...

   public string SomeMethod()
   {
       return "blah";
   }
}
```

Now you can just cast the object as that interface, if it works you invoke the method.

```
var subClass = obj as IYourInterface;
if ( subClass != null )
{
    var str = subClass.SomeMethod();  //done
}
```